# R 'adegenet' package: DNAbin2genind not formatting data correctly

Tags: r

I want to use the `adegenet` package to run analyses on genetic data. In order to do so I need to convert my fasta file into the genid file that adegenet recognizes.

I have tried inputting the data in two different ways with the same results.

```
>mydata.fasta <- fasta2DNAbin("~/Desktop/blattodeatest/Cryptocercuspunctulatus/COII.afa")

> mydata.fasta
22 DNA sequences in binary format stored in a matrix.

All sequences of same length: 404 

Labels: AB425873_COII AB425877_COII AB425878_COII AB425876_COII AB425880_COII AB425884_COII ...

Base composition:
a     c     g     t 
0.404 0.181 0.085 0.329 

>mydata.dna <- read.dna("~/Desktop/blattodeatest/Cryptocercus punctulatus/COII.afa", format="fasta")

> mydata.dna
22 DNA sequences in binary format stored in a matrix.

All sequences of same length: 404 

Labels: AB425873_COII AB425877_COII AB425878_COII AB425876_COII AB425880_COII AB425884_COII ...

Base composition:
a     c     g     t 
0.404 0.181 0.085 0.329
```

I then attempted to convert the data but get weird results.

```
>mydata.genind <- DNAbin2genind(mydata.fasta)
>mydata.genind
/// GENIND OBJECT /////////

 // 22 individuals; 91 loci; 189 alleles; size: 62.3 Kb

 // Basic content
   @tab:  22 x 189 matrix of allele counts
   @loc.n.all: number of alleles per locus (range: 2-3)
   @loc.fac: locus factor for the 189 columns of @tab
   @all.names: list of allele names for each locus
   @ploidy: ploidy of each individual  (range: 1-1)
   @type:  codom
   @call: DNAbin2genind(x = mydata.dna)

 // Optional content
   - empty -
```

There is only one 404bp locus in my data and it looks like the fasta file is getting read correctly. I cannot figure out why R thinks there are 91 loci after I use DNAbin2genind?

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that genind object considers each polymorphic position in the gene as a locus. To obtain the positions that are polym. in your original alignment type:

```
as.vector(mydata.genind@loc.names,mode="numeric")
```